# Вывести список дочерних рубрик Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Суть вопроса такая. Есть код

```
$cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'),false);
  $cat_parent = $cat->parent; // ID родительской категории
  $current_cat = get_query_var('cat'); // ID текущей категории
  if ($cat_parent == 0) {
  wp_list_categories('depth=2&hide_empty=0&title_li=&show_count=0&child_of='.$current_cat);
  } else {
  wp_list_categories('depth=2&hide_empty=0&title_li=&show_count=0&child_of='.$cat_parent); 
  }
```

с помощью которого выводятся дочерние рубрики текущей, либо дочерние рубрики родителя (если находишься на странице подкатегории).

Как можно вывести дочерние рубрики родительской рубрики, находясь на странице записи?

Это нужно для создания динамического меню.

Т.е. где бы мы ни находились, в категории, в под категории, на странице записи -
мы всегда видим меню, в котором содержатся подрубрики родительской, т.е. 1-го уровня.

Основная проблема на сколько я понимаю в том, что если пост принадлежит категории 3-го уровня, то в массиве нет данных о категории 1-го уровня, а только о родительской, т.е. категории 2-го уровня, т.к. она является родительской, для третьего. Собственно вопрос в том как вытащить информацию о категории 1-го уровня если пост принадлежит категории 3-го уровня. И так же вопрос как получить id категории первого уровня находясь на странице категории 3-го уровня, в массиве тоже информация только о его родителе, 2-м уровне. Вообще это возможно?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

Немного допилив свой код, удалось добиться нужного отображения на всех уровнях вложенности до 3-го, теперь мы имеем в садбаре всегда все дочерние рубрики не зависимо в какой именно рубрике мы находимся, пол дела сделано. Конечно может решение и не совсем правильное, но оно рабочее.

```
   <?php
    global $post;
      $category = get_the_category( get_the_ID() );
      $cat = get_category(get_query_var('cat'),false);
      $cat_parent = $cat->parent; // ID родительской категории
      $current_cat = get_query_var('cat'); // ID текущей категории
      $cat_top = $category[0]->parent;
      $ancestors = get_ancestors($cat_top, 'category');
      $ancestors_cat = $ancestors[0];
      if ($cat_parent == 0) {
      wp_list_categories('depth=2&hide_empty=0&title_li=&show_count=0&child_of='.$current_cat);
      }
      elseif ($ancestors[0]) {
      wp_list_categories('depth=2&hide_empty=0&title_li=&show_count=0&child_of='.$ancestors_cat);
      }
      else {
      wp_list_categories('depth=2&hide_empty=0&title_li=&show_count=0&child_of='.$cat_parent); 
      }
    ?>
```

Теперь осталось сделать все тоже самое для постов. В итоге мы получим Меню которое будет выводить все дочерние рубрики в сайдбар.

Comment: У вас и так выводятся подрубрики родительской. Или вам нужны подрубрики самой верхней из родительских рубрик?

Comment: Да, но только если мы находимся на страницах категорий.

Comment: Если мы находимся на странице записи, то выводятся все категории

Comment: Не могу понять как получить id родительской категории находясь на странице записи, что бы вывести ее дочерние рубрики

Comment: да просто: есть глобальная переменная $cat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Добавьте такую функцию в function.php вашей темы. Ее можно вызывать как из шаблона категории, так и из шаблона поста.

```
function cat_list_737863() {
    global $cat;

    $current_cat = $cat; // ID текущей категории
    if ( '' === $cat ) {
        // На странице поста
        $current_cat = get_the_category( get_the_ID() )[0]->cat_ID;
    }
    $cat_top = $current_cat; // ID самой верхней родительской категории
    while ( get_category( $cat_top )->category_parent ) {
        $cat_top = get_category( $cat_top )->category_parent;
    }
    echo '<ul class="children">';
    echo '<li class="cat-item cat-tem-' . intval( $cat_top ) . '">';
    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link($cat_top) . '">' . get_cat_name($cat_top) . '</a>';
    echo '<ul class="children">';
    wp_list_categories( 'hide_empty=0&title_li=&show_count=0&child_of=' . $cat_top );
    echo '</ul>';
    echo '</li>';
    echo '</ul>';
}
```

Работающий пример у меня на тестовом сайте: http://test.kagg.eu/uncategorized/

Comment: Данный код нормально работает только на страницах рубрик, при чем если находишься в рубрике 3-го уровня, то тоже не то выводит.

Comment: Если мы находимся на странице родительской рубрики http://mailrucp.bget.ru/?cat=1 все ок. Если находимся на странице дочерней рубрики 2-го уровня http://mailrucp.bget.ru/?cat=19 все ок. Если находимся на странице дочерней рубрики 3-го уровня http://mailrucp.bget.ru/?cat=23 то выводит дочерние рубрики рубрики 2-го уровня, а не первого как нужно. Ну и наконец находясь на странице записи http://mailrucp.bget.ru/?p=16 выводятся все категории, а не только те которые принадлежат родителю той рубрики в которой находится запись.

Comment: Кстати ваш код, выводит все рубрики, вне зависимости где находишься, т.е. просто выводит список всех рубрик.

Comment: исправлю чуть позже

Comment: >> а не только те которые принадлежат родителю той рубрики в которой находится запись. поправка, не родителю категории, а родителю первого уровня. Т.е. все время нужно получать id категории самого верхнего уровня, что бы выводить его дочерние рубрики.

Comment: К сожалению это совсем не то что нужно. Вот с верху в сайдбаре ваш код в низу мой http://mailrucp.bget.ru/?cat=1 ваш код показывает так как нужно только если находишься в родительской категории 1-го уровня. Если перейти в любую другую, то он начинает отсчет не с самого верха, а с предыдущей. И находясь в посте он так же не показывает всю цепочку категорий. На данный момент, мой код работает в категории 1-го и 2-го уровня, начиная с 3-го он показывает только на уровень вверх. А на страницах записи выводит все категории без разбора.

Comment: Основная проблема на сколько я понимаю в том, что если пост принадлежит категории 3-го уровня, то в массиве нет данных о категории 1-го уровня, а только о родительской, т.е. категории 2-го уровня, т.к. она является родительской, для третьего. Собственно вопрос в том как вытащить информацию о категории 1-го уровня если пост принадлежит категории 3-го уровня. И так же вопрос как получить id категории первого уровня находясь на странице категории 3-го уровня, в массиве тоже информация только о его родителе, 2-м уровне. Вообще это возможно?

Comment: Я сейчас исправлю ошибку у себя. Мой код не зависит от вложенном. А в вашем она ограничена 2 уровнями. Вы разве не видите depth?

Comment: Да вижу,  depth можно и поменять на 0, просто в данном случае мне нужна такая вложенность поэтому и написал. Но ваш код у меня не работает, почему то.

Comment: Исправил ошибку в коде, смотрите у меня на сайте. А насчет вложенности я не понял совсем.

Comment: Круто, вот посмотрите над поиском ваше под поиском мое, http://mailrucp.bget.ru/?cat=1 я все таки его тоже добил, правда ваше решение на много изящнее, а мое очень корявое, но работают оба. Правда мое действительно ограниченно уровнями, их конечно можно добавить, но придется еще условия прописывать, т.к. у меня все на условиях, наверно это не правильно, но я только учусь.